# How to choose which file to run and see its preview in a terminal when I have several in a same project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm programming in Visual Studio 2019.

In a project, I tried to run a file that I created next to an older one and see its preview on the terminal. The result is that it shows the preview of the older. How can I see this one instead of the older one in the terminal?

Comment: Show us your project directory structure, please.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: C:\Users\Gandoulf\Documents\Programmation\Apprentissage\CPP\LesLitteraux\LesLitteraux\
In this file there are 2 .cpp files, Source1.cpp and chaineDeCarateres.cpp

Comment: @Gandoulf "C:\Users\Gandoulf\Documents\Programmation\Apprentissage\CPP\LesLitteraux\LesLitteraux\ " - what's that supposed to tell us?

Comment: The software terminal runs the chaineDeCaractres.cpp file, I want to run the Source1.cpp

Comment: "In this file there are 2 files" - That doesn't make any sense. Files don't contain files. Did you mean "in this *directory* there are 2 files"?

Comment: in this project

Comment: "The software terminal runs the chaineDeCaractres.cpp file" - terminals don't run source files. They run executables - that is, compiled programs. Not individual files - C++ is *not* a scripting language.

Comment: yes, .exe files

Comment: So, do you see what to do next?

Comment: I can't send images, sorry